# Is it safe to remove "thermal-engine" from system/vendor/bin

Tags: root-access

I want to play PUBG on LG V20 so I renamed this file. Is it safe? Maybe it's safe until phone doesn't start turning off? Using LOS 15.1.

Comment: Umm, what does it have to do with playing PUBG? Did you rename this file because it's mentioned somewhere?

Comment: Yes. https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBGMobile/comments/99n9j1/one_plus_3t_fix_for_frame_lags It helps a lot to play PUBG

Comment: I think this question can not be answered as there is clear definition of "safe". The higher the temperature of your CPU gets and the longer it stays with this temperature the faster the CPU degrades and will die earlier. Therefore the only "safe way" is not to manipulate the system and not to play...

Comment: @Robert Okay, thanks, if you really want to play game, would you let GPU and CPU to heat up to 85°C?

Comment: What I would do does not matter, the only question is if you want to take the risk. As nobody knows how high the risk is there is not much we can do to you. You simply have to decide yourself if you want to accept the risk or you don't.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must find a way to disable thermal throttling in kernel modding (make custom kernel). Thermal driver will panic if you delete thermal-engine, mine after delete this all thermal driver enabled. I have to disable it every time phone booted

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).